# Iterating through Panel controls

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, controls

In a C# WinForm application I need to iterate all Controls which are type of TextBox. The TextBox ontrols are added dynamicaly.

```
        IEnumerable<TextBox> textBoxes = ActionsPanel.Controls.OfType<TextBox>();

        Debug.WriteLine(ActionsPanel.Controls.Count);

        foreach (TextBox textBox in textBoxes)
        {

        }
```

The code above does not work, in foreach I got nothing. Strangely if I count all the controls in panel I got real controls numberwhich are on the panel.

```
        Debug.WriteLine(textBoxes.Count());
```

Returns 0. What am I doing wrong here, it is really confusing.

Comment: This could be simply that the panel doesn't contain the controls. How did you add them to the ActionsPanel?

Comment: I was using `panel.Controls.Add(mytextbox);` to add example a Control of type TextBox. The Controls are also visible during aquiring them.

Comment: panel is ActionPanels  right?

Comment: Yes I should write ActionsPanel instead of panel here at stackoverflow.

Comment: Then something different is at play here. If the ActionsPanel.Controls.OfType doesn't return any textbox there are no textbox there. Something about a clear/remove of these boxes added?

Comment: I have to isolate what's going on there because I made a simple winform C# app only basic syntax without event handlers and such https://pastebin.com/Ss2xKRrX and it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145746/discussion-between-david-cery-and-steve).

Answer (score -1):

Found the solution, the problem was that all the TextBox controls were inside a TableLayoutPanel for better layout control, full source code here: pastebin.com/yz8JN4yr